# Show that $f(x)=0,\;0\leq x<1/2,\; f(x)=1,\;1/2\leq x\leq 1$ is Riemann integrable over $[0,1]$ and find its value.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration

> I want to prove that \begin{align} f:[0&,1]\to \Bbb{R}\\&x\mapsto  \begin{cases}0,&0\leq x<1/2,\\\\ 1,&1/2\leq x\leq 1. \end{cases}\end{align}
>   is Riemann integrable over $[0,1]$ and also, I want to find the value.

**MY TRIAL**

Let $\epsilon>0,\;x_1\in [0,1/2)$ and $x_2\in [1/2,1]$ such that $x_2-x_1<\epsilon.$ The set 
$$P=\{0,x_1,x_2,1  \}$$
forms a partition of $[0,1].$ Define $\Delta x_j=(x_j-x_{j-1})$ and $I_j=[x_{j-1}-x_j],\;j=1,2,3.$ So, the upper and lower Darboux sums are given by 
$$U(f,P)=\sum^{3}_{j=1}M_j \Delta x_j=1-x_1,\;\;\text{where}\;\;M_j=\sup_{x\in I_j}f(x),$$
$$L(f,P)=\sum^{3}_{j=1}m_j \Delta x_j=1-x_2.$$
Then,$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)=x_2-x_1<\epsilon.$$
Hence, $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[0,1]$.

I have been able to show, as seen above, that $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[0,1]$ but not able to find the value of the integral. I know that the answer is $1/2$ but can anyone help out by showing how I could arrive at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n\in\mathbb N$, let $P_n=\left\{0,\frac12,\frac12+\frac1{2n},1\right\}$. Compute $U(f,P_n)$ and $L(f,P_n)$ for each natural $n$. What do you get?

Comment: How did you think of that partition? No answer required! That's unthoughtful of me! Thanks, (+1)

Comment: That jump at $\frac12$ is what made me think of that partition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have thought of that, too! Anyway, thank you very much!